# jQuery UI Element vs Dojo (Dijit) Form Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dojo

Dojo seems to have a useful feature in that it can setup event handlers and default options, etc for Dijit.form elements as it is inserting it into the DOM.

For example, Dojo:

`var slider = new dijit.form.HorizontalSlider({
            name: sliderContainerId+'_slider',
            value: sliderValue,
            minimum: sliderMax,
            maximum: sliderMin,

            onChange: function(value){
   // some event handling  logic 
            }
        }, sliderContainerId);`

However, the jQuery UI Slider traditionally is applied to DOM elements that already exist:

`$( sliderContainerId ).slider({
   value:100,
   min: 0,
   max: 500,
   step: 50,
   slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
   }
  });`

I need to be able to 'programmatically' create new Sliders (and other form elements), but I'm not sure how that could be achieved with the way jQuery is structured? Maybe I'm missing something obvious here....

MTIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will absolutely let you create new elements on the fly.  `$("<div>").appendTo(".wrapper")` will create a new div element and add it to the element with id wrapper. In a larger example:

```
$("<div>").appendTo('.wrapper').slider({
    value:100, min: 0, max: 500, step: 50,
    slide: function( event, ui ) { $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value ); }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has a similar event registration.

The way of doing it is to use

```
$('.class').live(eventname, eventhandler);
```

Any element that is inserted into the dom that shares the same "class" will have its event hooked up automatically.

use http://www.jqapi.com for complete and comprehensive reference...

Answer (score 0):

You're right, jQueryUI's widgets work on elements that already exist in the DOM.

I don't *believe* jQueryUI has functionality like you're describing.  It's easy enough to mimic yourself though.  After you load in new content, you would just apply the `slider` function to the new html.  Assuming you do this on `ready` and inside an AJAX callback or similar, I would separate this initialization code into its own function that you can call from multiple places:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initializeSlider("#slider_div");
});

function initializeSlider(selector) {
    $(selector).slider({ 
        value:100, 
        min: 0, 
        max: 500, 
        step: 50, 
        slide: function(event, ui) { 
          $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value); 
        } 
    });         
}  

/* later on, when you insert new content, call initializeSlider again */

$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
      $("body").append(data.content); // append new html to the DOM.
      initializeSlider("#new_slider_element");
  }
});
```

I've never used Dojo, but I think this is the type of scenario you're talking about.